# Can I use AutoMapper to map one list to another list of already instantiated objects?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, automapper

I am using this code to map a list of DTO's to their EF counterparts. I'd like to eliminate the loop, not to mention the fetch. The latter I can do by caching all `Employee` objects in a dictionary, but I'm stuck on the loop.

```
var gridEmps = (List<EmployeeDescriptor>) employeeDescriptorBindingSource.DataSource;
Mapper.CreateMap<EmployeeDescriptor, Employee>();
foreach (var newEmp in gridEmps)
{
    var oldEmp = context.Employees.Single(emp => emp.Id == newEmp.Id);
    Mapper.Map(newEmp,oldEmp);
}
```

As used above, AutoMapper maps from my DTO to an already instantiated entity object, but if I were to try this using two lists, like so,

```
var gridEmps = (List<EmployeeDescriptor>) employeeDescriptorBindingSource.DataSource;
var dbEmps = context.Employees.ToList();

Mapper.CreateMap<EmployeeDescriptor, Employee>();
Mapper.Map(gridEmps, dbEmps);
```

how will AutoMapper know how to link the correct objects from one list to the other, based on their key property? I know the key property is also mapped, but surely this will mess with the EF change tracking?

How can I tell AutoMapper to link source and destination objects by their key properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not found how to tell auto mapper collection merging rules without loops. My solution is following:

1. Create `TypeConvertor`: `List<EmployeeDescriptor> -> List<Employee>`

   ```
   Mapper
     .CreateMap<List<EmployeeDescriptor>, List<Employee>>()
     .ConvertUsing(new EmployeeListConverter());
   ```
2. Put your loops inside Convert method of the `EmployeeListConverter`
3. Use `Mapper.Map(gridEmps, dbEmps);`